# Google Glass: menu and card font size styling

Tags: android, fonts, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to style the font size for a `Menu` item?

How about for a regular `Card` item that is placed inside an activity? (not for `Live Card` or `Static Card`)

If possible for the `Menu` item, can this be done inside the code itself versus in an `XML`? Reason I ask is I am dynamically inflating a menu.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on your precise question, but one suggestion would be to look at how the `Timer` sample app creates a `SelectValueActivity`.

In that sample, that activity is used to select a value from 1-60.

It behaves very similarly to a `Menu`, and you can completely customize the view.

There very well may be a simpler way to do what you're getting at, but maybe this helps a bit.